# VB.net Form does not open however icon visible in task bar

Tags: windows, vb.net, forms, display, desktop

I get strange problem with a VB.net desktop app: it uses a main form which opens normally. This one has several menu buttons to open different other forms. Since some weeks - so it worked properly before -, one form does not appears anymore (form.show in VB code). The app icon is still displayed in the Windows task bar, it's not "frozen" and, when Alt+Tab keys are used, the form which should be opened is displayed with a white frame in the list of opened apps.

When this app is edited (with Visual Studio), the form is displayed without any trouble.

OS is Windows 11.

Would you have any idea of the reason and the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Mybe it's out of screen rect. try set the location of the form to (0;0)

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was in the user.config file, where position and size parameters are recorded.

I don't know for which reason, but the app recorded form location with these values: -3200, -3200. Modify them solved the problem.